# How to avoid checkpoint or using HDFS in spark streaming when using mapwithState?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using mapwithState in my java spark streaming application, and I would like to avoid doing a checkpoint. The reason for this is that I do not want to install HDFS. I believe a checkpoint is only required for fault tolerance.

However, if I do not care about fault tolerance, is it possible to skip the checkpoint, but still use mapwithState?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, **`checkpoint`** directory configuration is mandatory for **`mapWithState`** operator. It is not only for fault tolerance, it is also for storing the previous state of object in HDFS. One alternative you can try by providing **`local file system`** path as checkpoint directory when running application in **`local mode`**.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to skip the checkpoint with mapWithState?
>
> **No. At least not till Spark-2.0.**

[mapWithState](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaPairDStream.html#mapWithState(org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec)) uses checkpoint directory to store state of the streaming data. That is the cost you have to pay for making Spark Streaming stateful. You should consider using [Kryo Serialization](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization) in case building stateful applications with Spark streaming.

Snapshot from [databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/01/faster-stateful-stream-processing-in-apache-spark-streaming.html).

[image]